# UV - sharp edge and uv seams overlapping

Tags: uv

[image]

how can i disable sharp edges when adding uv seams because this is really confusing and annoying unlike in 3ds max when you are in unwrap editor automatically all of your selection is only for unwrap unlike in blender everything is there so it was confusing when you export it you thought that everything has its seams but eventually you know when baked there was error.

my eyes doubled sharp and seams at the same time, my works double because of this overlapping i always need to remove the sharp just to check if my uv seams are really applied on the mesh.  I hope you can help me for this its really frustrating an an-innovative. I shift from 3ds max because of blender is free but I might go back to 3ds max because its not really that nice to have this very simple yet it makes complicated.

Comment: I'm sure when you first started using Max, some things were pretty hard to find, there,  too ....

Comment: Sharp edges are not marked automatically by themselves. If they are marked as sharp then you marked them as sharp. You can disable sharp from displaying as is outlined in the answer. Thing is one has to do this only if edges are marked as sharp and seams at the same time

Answer (score 3):

When you are in edit mode you press `N`. Then search for the box called `Mesh Display` under `Overlays` you can uncheck the options you want to hide.

[image]